# Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: object 'C_crspl' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to add a `geom_smooth()` to a `qplot()` with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2movies)
qplot(votes, rating, data = movies) + geom_smooth()
```

However, the smoother is missing from the plot. I also receive the following warning message:

> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: object 'C_crspl' not found

Does anybody know what is wrong here?

This is my setup:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a sample dataset to illustrate the issue that you are encountering. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The sample dataset is `movies` from the library `ggplot2movies`.

Comment: The above code works without any issues. What if you try the following: `qplot(votes, rating, data = movies, geom = c("point", "smooth"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar issues:

```
# `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
# Warning message:
# Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
# object 'C_crspl' not found
```

and

```
# Warning message:
# Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
# object 'C_magic' not found
```

when using `geom_smooth(method="gam")`. The problems vanished when I explicitly loaded the `mgcv` package version `1.8-17`. I guess by default, ggplot (I use `2.2.1.9000`) looked at `1.8-16`, which was also in the search path. So you might want to update `mgcv` or make sure that the latest version is used.

Comment: I was really hoping that this was the underlying cause, because I was facing this issue while using a GAM smooth, but this does not appear to solve the issue, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce your problem: it works fine in my system. I guess you have a problem with some ggplot2 dependency. Try restarting your session and reinstall ggplot2.

If that doesn't work, test `geom_smooth()` with a different dataset and a different method, e.g. `qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm')`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue. Tried loading `mgcv` explicitly and this did nothing. Since I originally relied on `ggplot2` to install `mgcv`, I went back and installed `mgcv` myself so that the newest version was included and then re-installed `ggplot2` and the issue went away. This is on Ubuntu 16.04 with `ggplot2` 2_2.2.1 and `mgcv` 1.8-23.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and almost gave up. However, when I simply reinstalled mgcv before and ggplot2 later, the script simply went back to working as before.