# simple visualization of GAM model in R

Tags: r

I am using this:

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

model <- gam(
    Petal.Width ~

    s(Sepal.Length)

    , data = iris
    , method = "REML"
)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = Petal.Width ~ s(Sepal.Length))
```

but get this error:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
object 'Petal.Width' not found
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640913/computation-failed-in-stat-smooth-object-c-crspl-not-found

Comment: Two things: your `gam` models x&y are in a different order from your plot. Within the `geom_smooth` call don't use the variable names, use `formula = y ~ s(x)` (also `mgcv::gam` has a plot method, so you can get a simple plot using `plot(model, shade=1, scale=0, residuals = TRUE, cex=4)` but is obviously useful as more smooths are added to the model )

Comment: @user20650 - using formula = y ~ s(x) solves it - thanks! Please post answer.